# Wrong sound is playing when I run my android app

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android app.

Recently, I got some VOC issues from the user.
The issue is that when the user just launches the app, a weird sound is playing.

I caught that the sound is from the Ads.
Users said that they cannot see the Ads, but only hear the sound.

My app has Reward Ads which was already applied over a year ago.
The only recent changes were in response to GDPR.

In MainActivity.onCreate():

```kotlin
MobileAds.initialize(this)
MobileAds.setAppMuted(true)
```

I already called `setAppMuted(true)`!

Is there any known issue or solution about this?

I think flutter sdk has same issue.
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/502

But I am not sure in Android.

Comment: For anyone to help in this issue, some code and more information is required to understand what is going on in your application.